# REGEXP_MATCH multiple words in a string using CASE statement in Google DataStudio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, case-statement, re2

I am using *Google Datastudio* to make a `CASE` statement to take a multi-words string and split it out into categories. I was asked to use REGEXP_MATCH (nothing else, I know `contains` function would be easier).

I need a solution to match the following words:

```
HouseBrochure 
home brochure 
HomeBrochure 
house brochure 
Bathroom brochure 
Bathroombrochure 
FloorBrochure 
floor brochure
```

To complicate matters, these words come in via a website request system, meaning people can request a *house*, *bathroom* and *floor* brochure in one request. When such requests reach my server, it compiles into a list(string) which looks like this:

```
# (with the pipes included)
HouseBrochure|Bathroom brochure|floor brochure
```

This is just an example of 1 request, there are many variations and multiple requests that come through (I've also only included a few of these brochures, there are many more)

I need to separate out all the `house brochures`, all the `bathroom brochures` and all the `floor brochures` etc, so I can count how many requests have been made for each brochure.

Being new to Regex, I have a basic understanding but nowhere near advanced.
My current attempt in Data studio looks like this:

```sql
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Event Label,'^.*(HouseBrochure.*|home brochure.*|HomeBrochure.*|house brochure.*).*$') THEN 'Home Brochure'
END
```

This is just for the home brochure, yet it's not working, can someone help?
Also, as an FYI `Datastudio` uses REG2

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought i might not have explained it perfectly well so I can clarify a few things hopefully.

the string i gave above was an example of a request type - the user may request multiple brochures at the same time. when i extract it will look like this:

Home brochure|HomeBrochure|house brochure    -  10
HomeBrochure                                 - 3
house brochure|BathroomBrochure|HomeBrochure - 4

Comment: Meaning 4 people requested both a house and bathroom brochure, and 10 people requested a home, home and house brochure.

I need to be able to run a count of people requesting a bathroom brochure a house brochure etc. In the above example, I would count 10 bathroom brochures and 17 HomeBrochures.

Hopefully this makes sense and hopefully there is a solution to split out each brochure and run a count.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

1. convert everything to lower case (avoid messing with upper/lower case differences)
2. Use regex to replace variations with base form:

e.g.

```
(house|home)\s*brochure
```

replace with

```
HomeBrochure
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/uJUqyw/1).

3. Do some counting as needed, using just the base keywords.